# Authenticating with Stack Overflow programmatically

Tags: iphone, openid

I would like to add up and down voting to my iPhone application - [MyStacks](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/mystacks/id360030953?mt=8). for this I need the to be able to authenticate the user with Stack Overflow.

I'm look at adapting the [Twitter-OAuth-iPhone](http://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone) library. However the problem I have is obtaining the consumer and secret key. to use OAuth, do I need to obtain a different key for each provider? In order to [obtain a consumer key](https://www.google.com/accounts/ManageDomains) from Google the application needs to have a domain name, but this being an iPhone app of course I don't have one. Does this mean that I can't use OAuth?

Is there any other way to programmatically authenticate with Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution, on the iPhone its surprisingly simple. Just embed a UIWebView which opens up the SO login page and then once users authenticates themselves the required cookies will be saved using NSHTTPCookieStorage so you can simply use NSURLRequest as normal.